# Max. no. of connections that SQLite database can provide

Tags: java, database, sqlite, sqlconnection

**What is the maximum no. of connections that SQLite database can provide?**

I'm using SQLite database with Java for the development of small desktop application. After few successful connection I got error message like this:

> SQLite database file is locked.

What are the probable reason?

*I am expecting helpful answer from you. Thank You in advance!*

Comment: I am expecting sufficient research from you. [What is the maximum connections for sqlite3 database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017762/what-is-the-maximum-connections-for-sqlite3-database)

Comment: [1.0 File Locking And Concurrency In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)

Comment: Thank You @JonnyHenly for your response! I am unable to detect SQLite version, I just tried to create db.sqlite, so I posted this question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one connection that mutates your data. Close your idling connections or move to MySQL if you need concurrency

Comment: I think it's better to use SQLite database rather than using MySQL, for small application.